# Module in Joomla 3 appearing where it sohuldn't

Tags: joomla3.0, joomla-module

I've created a custom HTML module and it appears on some random pages, even though it is assigned only to the homepage. Does anybody have an idea why and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Joomla only knows how to assign module positions precisely by menu item ID. If a page does not have a menu item ID then Joomla is forced to make an assumption, that the module assignments are the same as the *default page*. Unless you specified something else in your menu then the default page is the homepage.

The solution is to create menu items for pages where you want to change behaviour. In the case of category pages like blogs, then creating a menu item for the parent category is enough.

Comment: Hey Seth, thanks for the answer. I really though it would work, but I tried assigning a menu item for each of these pages, and they are now on the list of the menu items but still not ticked in the Menu Assignment tab of this module, and still the module is appearing on them..! If it helps, they are all of the same category, but I can't see any difference between them and the articles in other categories (that's somehow relevant) except that they were added after the module was installed...

Comment: Update- It works only when the menu and these articles as part of the menu are published. But I don't want them to appear in any menu... Any other way?

Comment: Create another menu, in menu manager, and add the links to the pages you need to control module place in to that menu. You don't have to publish that menu anywhere on your site, it's enough simply that the links exist in the database.

Comment: Hey, did that, still not working... /: any idea why?

Comment: You've not followed my instructions completely…